# Add application to right click context menu on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, pdf

I have a small app that combines selected Finder items into a single PDF. I most often use this to merge multi page PDF's into a single file.

This app won't show up in the right click menu for selected (PDF) files. Of course I don't want to make this the default app for opening PDF's. All other PDF-related apps automatically show up in the context menu, but not this one.

What can I do to make this app show up in the right click menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the "Open With" sub menu?

If so, the contents are controlled by LaunchServices and you may need to rebuild your Launch Services database or you could state that you can handle .pdf files with a UTI in your Info.plist.

To rebuild the Launch Services Database:
Using 10.4:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user /
```

Using 10.5/10.6 the location changed to CoreServices.framework:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user /
```

Adding the UTI information is something best asked at Stack Overflow however.

Comment: Thanks! Fixing Info.plist and rebuilding Launch Services did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

[OnMyCommand](http://www.abracode.com/free/cmworkshop/) is a framework for customising and adding commands to the right-click menu on a Mac. It's well worth checking out... There's a basic tutorial [here](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/06/12/how-to-add-commands-to-the-os-x-right-click-menu/).